# Re-Calculate width after browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running a third party script and it calculates an element's width upon loading. It works great but I have a responsive website and when I re-size the browser the element is no longer displayed correctly.

Here is the code that is used to calculate the width:

```
var w = ticker.width();
if (label.length) w -= label.outerWidth() + parseFloat(label.css("margin-right"));
if (controls.length) w -= controls.outerWidth() + parseFloat(controls.css("margin-left"));
news.css("width", w);
```

How do I modify this part of the script to re-calculate the width when the browser is resized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what work best

```
$(window).resize(function() {
if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
    this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).trigger('windowResize');
    }, 500); 
});
$(window).on('windowResize', function() {
   console.log($(window).width()); // calculating here
});
```

reason for having timeout is that window takes some time to get settel the width but classic `window.resize` event get triggers before it setteled down

Comment: very nice, clean & practical

Comment: can you explain why one is resize() and the other is on() ?

Comment: windowResize is the custom event passed by me so to listen that i use on()

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
   //your code to calculate the width
});
```